# Serialization inheritance: Will an exception be thrown if the base class isn't marked [Serializable]?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, serializable

Taking a practice exam the exam said I got this one wrong. The answer marked in Yellow is the supposed correct answer.

In the following quote, the part marked in bold I think is wrong: "The Serializable attribute is not inherited by the derived classes, so if you only mark the Encyclopedia class with the Serializable attribute, **the runtime will throw an exception when trying to serialize the Name field**".

[image]

I actually created a sample project with an `Animal` class and a `Cat` class that derives from it. I marked the `Cat` class `[Serializable]` and the `Animal` class is not.

I was able to successfully serialize and deserialize the `Cat` class, including the `Animal` properties.

Is this a .NET version issue? The exam is 70-536, so it's targeting 2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the base class also needs to be serializable. Some easy test code:

```
  public class Animal
    {
        public Animal()
        {
            name = "Test";
        }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Cat : Animal
    {
        public string color {get; set;}
    }


        var acat = new Cat();
        acat.color = "Green";
        Stream stream = File.Open("test.bin", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        bformatter.Serialize(stream, acat);
        stream.Close();
```

When you try to serialize, you get this error:

Type 'SerializeTest.Animal' in Assembly 'SerializeTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

edit - I notice that you did the same thing but it worked for you. Do you have the code you used? This one is in .net 4, but I don't think its changed that much between versions.

Comment: Hmmm...ok, so maybe the reason my test succeeded was I was implementing custom serializing. Now that I think of it, I think that's why. But if you do it your way with the default serializing, it will get an exception. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, yeah. Custom serialization (and even some of the other built in serializers) ignore the [Serializable] attribute. They could probably make the question a bit clearer on that. :)

Comment: That's the problem with these test questions. They are mostly of the trick question variety than the how-much-do-you-know variety.